# raw_input and dict

Tags: python, dictionary, raw-input

I'm attempting to either put the value from "room" as the key, and "acquity" as the value a dictionary or each time the code runs have the end value "acquity" assigned to a new variable (it needs to run 32 times for 32 rooms). I cannot figure this out, sorry very new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def main():

var=0

        while (var<33):

            room=raw_input("Input patient room Number ")




                ##Lists and prints/input for Procedural acuity
            print "1- No Procedures"
            print "2- IV Starts, Foley Catheter"
            print "3- Vitals, Neuro Check, Bladder Scans"
            print "4- Bedside Procedure, Physician post-op, frequent catheterization"
            a=raw_input("Input Procedural Acuity 1-4 ")

                ##Lists and prints/input for Nutritional acuity
            print "1- Setup Self"
            print "2- Ordering Assistance"
            print "3- Feed"
            print "4- Tubefeed, Aspiration Procedures"
            b=raw_input("Input Nutritional Acuity 1-4 ")

                ##Lists and prints/input for Medication acuity
            print "1- Minimal Oral"
            print "2- Moderate PO/IV"
            print "3- Dysphasia/Multi IV"
            print "4- Chemo/GTUBE/Complex IV"
            c=raw_input("Input Medication Acuity 1-4 ")

                ##Lists and prints/input for Mobility acuity
            print "1- Ad lib"
            print "2- Assist of SB"
            print "3- Assist of 1"
            print "4- Assist of 2"
            d=raw_input("Input Mobility Acuity 1-4 ")

                ##Lists and prints/inputs for Behavioral Acuity
            print "1- Calls Appropriately/No Needs"
            print "2- Some Education/ Calls Often"
            print "3- Anxious/ Calls Frequently"
            print "4- New Diagnosis, Calls very frequently, highly anxious"
            e=raw_input("Input Behavioral Acuity 1-4 ")

            a=float(a)
            b=float(b)
            c=float(c)
            d=float(d)
            e=float(e)

            Acuity1= a+b+c+d+e
            print "Patient in room %s, is graded at acuity %s"%(room, Acuity1)
            var= var + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: are you using python3 or 2?

Comment: I just tested it, well i fixed a few things but it works, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: The portion that I posted is functional (although admittedly ugly), I guess I was just looking for clues as to how to go about my next step, which is each time the code is run I need for the input of room number to be converted to a variable (room1, room2 etc etc) and for the acuity of the patient in that room to be set equal to the room variable. Sorry this might be a little much to ask. Thanks for cleaning up my code by the way.

Comment: Yep, I think @jamylak's solution incorporates that

Comment: Thank you as well Holiday, appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of your `main()`, let's change the name to `get_roomnumbers_dict` add:

```
def get_roomnumbers_dict():
    var=0    
    d = {} # this line to initalize the dictionary

    while (var<33):
        .....
```

At the end of your function:

```
        .....
        Acuity1= a+b+c+d+e
        print "Patient in room %s, is graded at acuity %s"%(room, Acuity1)
        d[int(room)] = Acuity1 # saves to the dictionary
        var= var + 1
        # end of while loop here

    return d # returns dictionary for someone to check acuity and room number
```

So then in your code you can simply have:

```
acquity_by_roomnumber = get_roomnumbers_dict() # and that gets the dictionary
```

Comment: Thanks very much! A couple more things, I'm getting float object does not support item assignment error, I'm guessing I have to convert acuity to an integer? Sorry I feel terrifically dense.

Comment: @user2229838 nope, that means you are mixing up variables. You may have defined `d` somewhere else as a `float`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `raw_input` with `input`! I had the same error earlier! :P
Also add `import sys` to the top!